# Why does OAuth2AuthorizedClientService requires spring-boot-starter-web to autowire?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to write an OAuth2 Client SpringBoot app that :

- Does ***NOT*** require a web container ( no Tomcat nor Jetty ) ...
- To basically send an Authorization bearer header ( either opaque or JWT bearer token ) in an HTTP request to another SpringBoot app that acts an OAuth2 resource server.

Now looking at the documentation here :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7/servlet/oauth2/client/core.html#oauth2Client-client-registration-repo

.. it says that both *OAuth2AuthorizedClientService* and *ClientRegistrationRepository* should be auto-wired automatically:

```java
@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService;

@Autowired
private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
```

presumably by just having :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But it turns out that I also need :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

for the auto-wiring to work. Otherwise, I get :

```
Field oAuth2AuthorizedClientService in org.example.oauth2client.FeignConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' in your configuration.
```

So question is, why is `spring-boot-starter-web` needed to have the auto-wiring to work ?

I don't want to add a web container as the OAuth2 client SpringBoot app does not require it ( e.g. command-line app ) but needs to consume a REST service from another SpringBoot app running as an OAuth2 resource server.

Answer (score 4):

OK ... I found the answer, though not what I was expecting.

`DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` is asserting and expecting a `HttpServletRequest`:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.7.x/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java#L144

So the spring security's OAuth2 client only works in the context of where the client app is running in a web server container.

It looks like I then cannot use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` for apps that are not running in a web server container. ( e.g. command line or batch application ), but why ???

In this case, what options do we have ?