# How to make a oauth2 authentication wihtin spring boot shell application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shell, oauth, keycloak

I'm writing a spring boot shell application which should access a rest API which is protected by keycloak. In a web application is everything fine. The browser redirects me to keycloak and keycloak back to my application and voilà I'm authenticated.

But in Cli/Shell application without browser it seems to be impossible.

All I want is to get an access token to attach it to each rest request. Like this:

```
POST {{realmUri}}/protocol/openid-connect/token 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json

grant_type=password
&username={{username}}
&password={{userPassword}}
&client_id={{clientId}}
&client_secret={{clientSecret}}
&scope=openid+phone
```

That returns the access token. How can I achieve this via spring security oauth.
The "Resource Owner Password Flow" should be the right thing but it is not inplemented.

But I think it must be possible.

Maybe OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider could do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my final solution:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TokenService {

    private OAuth2User currentUser;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public static class OAuth2AccessTokenResponse {
        @JsonProperty(OAuth2ParameterNames.ACCESS_TOKEN)
        private String accessToken;

        @JsonProperty(OAuth2ParameterNames.EXPIRES_IN)
        private String expiresIn;

        @JsonProperty("refresh_expires_in")
        private String refreshExpiresIn;

        @JsonProperty(OAuth2ParameterNames.REFRESH_TOKEN)
        private String refreshToken;

        @JsonProperty(OAuth2ParameterNames.TOKEN_TYPE)
        private String tokenType;

        @JsonProperty("not-before-policy")
        private String notBeforePolicy;

        @JsonProperty("session_state")
        private String sessionState;

        @JsonProperty(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE)
        private String scope;
    }

    @Data
    @Builder
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class OAuth2User {
        private final Jwt accessToken;
        private final OAuth2AccessTokenResponse response;

        public String getRefreshToken() {
            return response.refreshToken;
        }
    }

    private final OAuth2ClientProperties tokenServiceProperties;
    private final RestTemplate simpleRestTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().build();;

    protected OAuth2User resposeToUser(OAuth2AccessTokenResponse response) {
        var jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders
                .fromIssuerLocation(tokenServiceProperties.getProvider().get("keycloak").getIssuerUri());
        Jwt accessToken = jwtDecoder.decode(response.getAccessToken());
        return OAuth2User.builder().accessToken(accessToken).response(response).build();
    }

    public OAuth2User authenticateUser(String username, String password) {
        log.info("Try to login user {}", username);
        var token = sendUserAuthenticationRequest(username, password);
        log.debug("User {} successfully log in {}", username, token);
        currentUser = token;
        return currentUser;
    }

    OAuth2User sendUserAuthenticationRequest(String username, String password) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("grant_type", "password");
        map.add("client_id", tokenServiceProperties.getRegistration().get("keycloak").getClientId());
        map.add("username", username);
        map.add("password", password);
        var token = sendKeycloakRequest(map);
        return resposeToUser(token);
    }

    OAuth2User sendTokenRefreshRequest(String refreshToken) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
        map.add("client_id", tokenServiceProperties.getRegistration().get("keycloak").getClientId());
        map.add("refresh_token", refreshToken);
        var token = sendKeycloakRequest(map);
        return resposeToUser(token);
    }

    OAuth2AccessTokenResponse sendKeycloakRequest(MultiValueMap<String, String> map) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> exchange = simpleRestTemplate.exchange(
                tokenServiceProperties.getProvider().get("keycloak").getTokenUri(), HttpMethod.POST, request,
                OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.class);
        return exchange.getBody();
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        if (currentUser == null) {
            throw new CliException(ErrorCode.user_not_logged_in);
        }
        if (currentUser.accessToken.getExpiresAt().isBefore(Instant.now())) {
            log.info("Refresh token {}", currentUser.accessToken);
            currentUser = sendTokenRefreshRequest(currentUser.getRefreshToken());
        }
        return currentUser.accessToken.getTokenValue();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RestTemplate in Spring Boot to send a POST request to the Keycloak token endpoint with the necessary parameters (grant_type, username, password, etc.), then extract the access token from the response and attach it to your REST API requests as a bearer token for authentication.

Comment: It's good idea but I hoped there's a cooler way to do that.
In that for instance: new OAuthAuthenticator().authenticate(new UserPassword("admin", "password")) => and token is automaticlly available in the system

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74957451/619830) interesting. Apparently, you have no other choice than building the POST request by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and of course this way is **deprecated**. Someone a better idea? How can I achieve the same with not deprecated classes?

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizationContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.PasswordOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    private final OAuth2ClientProperties tokenServiceProperties;

    public String login(String username, String password) {
        var clientConfig = new OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper(tokenServiceProperties).asClientRegistrations();
        OAuth2AuthorizationContext oAuth2AuthorizeContext = OAuth2AuthorizationContext
                .withClientRegistration(clientConfig.get("keycloak")).attributes(attrs -> {
                    attrs.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username);
                    attrs.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, password);
                    attrs.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
                }).principal(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("no", "matter")).build();

        var user = new PasswordOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider().authorize(oAuth2AuthorizeContext);
        return user.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run() {
        System.out.println(login("myapp_user_user", "password"));
        return aa -> {
        };
    }

}
```

And the application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=my-app
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=password
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:5050/realms/MyRealm
```